# How to add [assembly: PexLinqPackage] to a test project

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, pex, pex-and-moles

I am trying to get Pex to work with linq in my project.  I got this explanation on what I need to do:

```
In order for Pex to support Linq, make sure you add a reference to
Microsoft.Pex.Linq.dll and add the [assembly: PexLinqPackage] 
attribute to the test project.
```

I have the reference added.  But I have never had to add anything like **[assembly: PexLinqPackage]** to a project.  How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick any file in the test project (`AssemblyInfo.cs` will do just fine) and add a `[assembly: PexLinqPackage]` line to it.

You can use absolutely any file to add assembly-level attributes, but `AssemblyInfo.cs` seems to be the best choice since it already contains several assembly-level attributes.

Comment: I agree with Anton, but I would go farther and recommend AssemblyInfo.cs over putting it in just any file -- keep all your assembly attribute adornments in one place so that they are easier to find and manage.